# Shiny: how to combine radio button with numericInput

Tags: shiny

I am new to Shiny. And I was wondering how could I combine radio button with numericInput ? My target is like this. Thanks in advance.

[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLcNj.png).

Actually I have no idea how to combine the radio button with numericInput. So I only have a simple example with radio button so far.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(        
tags$h4("Select Method for Testing"),
         radioButtons('testing', '',
            c("Fraction of cases selected at random",
             "K-fold cross-validation"))

          ))




server<-function(input, output,session) {

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please see this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example.